# How to append URL parameter when redirecting to an identity provider

Tags: c#, identityserver4

I would like to append a `login_hint` parameter when redirecting to Azure AD. The reason is that I already know the username and don't want the user to have to specify it again.

In Identity Server we set up identity providers like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddOpenIdConnect()
```

From the account controller we can challenge a new login to an identity provider by calling:

```
var properties = this.signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl, userId);

return this.Challenge(properties, provider);
```

But how can we include additional parameters to the provider and more specifically to the URL that the user will be redirected to? There is a dictionary in `AuthenticationProperties` where we can add arbitrary data, so I guess we can consume these somewhere before user is redirected.

I know that there is the `whr` and `domain_hint` (sort of similar to what I want to achieve) property in the protocol message, but where and when can we access these or add custom parameters in the pipeline?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A short while after I posted this I found a solution. First I add the userId in `AuthenticationProperties`.

```
var properties = this.signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl, userId);

properties.Items["userId"] = userId;

return this.Challenge(properties, provider);
```

When registering the identity provider there is an event in `OpenIdConnectOptions` where we can set `LoginHint`.

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddOpenIdConnect("test", "test", options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "xxx";
        options.ClientId = "xxx";
        options.Scope.Add(IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId);
        options.Scope.Add(IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile);
        options.Scope.Add(IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email);
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            NameClaimType = ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType,
            RoleClaimType = ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType
        };
        options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = ctx =>
        {
            if (ctx.Properties.Items.TryGetValue("userId", out var userId))
            {
                ctx.ProtocolMessage.LoginHint = userId;
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
    });
```